# Hooking API Calls in Current Process?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

How do I go about hooking/redirecting a function in a DLL (say, `CreateThread` from Kernel32.dll) loaded in the *current* process?

(I don't have control over which pieces of code call `CreateThread`, so it's not like I can just have the code something else instead.)

The language doesn't matter much; I'm guessing C/C++ would be the best choices for this.

---

Update:

I forgot to mention: I'm *not* looking for solutions that require the bundling of extra libraries into my program; I was looking for a manual way of doing the hooking (such as by rewriting the address of the function), not for using an external library to do this.

But thanks to those who mentioned an external library; sorry I didn't say this earlier.

Comment: also check this article: [API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://easyhook.codeplex.com/

It's an API Hooking framework.
Its open source, very easy to use!

Comment: Thanks for the link; unfortunately, I'd already heard (and used) EasyHook, but I was looking for a more lightweight solution to the problem. (I don't want to load an entire library just to hook a single function.)

Comment: Check out "WinAPIOverride32" - its a pretty open source application to run perform API hook to explore/research applications.
They don't have a whole framework, so you can check out their code as an example to what you want to achieve.

Comment: WHOA interesting! I'd never heard of that one. :) Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: Hm... does it still require loading an external DLL? There's several mentions of different libraries. (I guess I could just insert the source into my own program; I'll try that..)

Comment: That's what I meant :-)
You can just use the source as an example.

btw, its a great application!

Answer (score 3):

there's MS library for this: [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)

Comment: Hm... I'd heard of Detours but never used it. How lightweight is it? I think it requires loading another library... and I guess I should've stated, I need to avoid that.

Comment: it's pretty lightweight and source code is public, but license forces you to use it as DLL. in any case you can check how they do this

Answer (score 3):

*(This most likely would have been more appropriate as a "comment" under the "Detours" answer, but, as my "reputation" isn't enough yet to add comments I guess, let me post it as an answer)*

[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.audio/msg/71a4c49c2fbd714d) under [this thread ("DirectShow question")](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.audio/browse_thread/thread/b174cd34dc13d7fa/71a4c49c2fbd714d) mentions a replacement/home-grown alternative to Detours (with some rough code example as well) by Alessandro Angeli.

I've actually first found it quoted in [another thread ("problem in hooking cocreateinstance")](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video/browse_thread/thread/1883c0cd211cccc6?fwc=1) while also searching for COM component creation hooking/tracing (This second thread is more focused on cross-process hooking though).

Let me also add a link for [WinAPIOverride32](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/) (by Jacquelin Potier) for convenience here as well. It seems to have "developer designed GUI" :) but, no complaints at all as it is open source (as mentioned above).